# Kohana 3.2 in subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana, subdirectory

I need to put Kohana 3.2 project to subdirectory.

Now when I type http://web_ip/subdirectory it run properly (default controller load ok). But, when I type: http://web_ip/subdirectory/kategoria/7,pokoj-dzienny i get (404 Not found requested url).

.htaccess

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

in application/bootstrap.php

```
Kohana::init(array(
   'base_url' => '/subdirectory',
   'index_file' => '',
));

        Route::set('kategoria', 'kategoria/(<id>(,<nazwa>))')
            ->defaults(array(
                'directory' => 'strona',
                'controller' => 'kategoria',
                'action'     => 'kategoria',
            ));
        Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>(/<id2>))))')
            ->defaults(array(
                'directory' => 'strona',
                'controller' => 'welcome',
                'action'     => 'index',
            ));
```

Please help, what should I change?

Comment: `RewriteBase /` - what it supposed to do?

Comment: Change to: RewriteBase /subdirectory/

Comment: I changed RewriteBase  but nothing has changed. Any other idea?